# PHP passing variables into a function

Tags: php, function

This is really basic PHP. Can someone tell me why this does not work and what I need to do to make it work.

```
<?php
$test_var=12;
proc_scrn($test_var);

proc_scrn($local_pid)
{
echo "tp12",$local_pid ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Declare the function before the call ?

Comment: +1, try adding `function` before proc_scrn. And I am not sure if the echo-part will work. Try changing it to `echo "tp12".$local_pid;`

Comment: @Nanocom Functions do not need to be declared before being called

Comment: @OptimusCrime That `echo` statement is fine and is actually faster than concatenation

Comment: There's no need to define function before its called ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you haven't actually created a function there. This would work:

```
<?php
$test_var=12;
proc_scrn($test_var);

function proc_scrn($local_pid='')
{
echo "tp12: ".$local_pid;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function proc_scrn($local_pid)
{
// something
}
```

[PHP- User-defined functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Comment: a perfect answer with no offtopic chatter.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple

```
<?php 
$var=1;
function proc_scrn($var1){
    echo "tp12: ".$var1;
}
proc_scrn($var);
?>
```